# Translate string with URL in web2py

Tags: hyperlink, internationalization, web2py

A simple question - If I have a web page view in web2py with a string like

```
Here is a string to <a href="{{=URL('my_other_page', vars=vars)}}">translate</a>.
```

What is the approved way to apply the `T()` operator to it so that I can provide different language translations, but keep the same url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation string can include *interpolated* variables as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Internationalization--and-Pluralization-with-T). For example:

```
T('Here is a string to <a href="%(url)s">translate</a>',
  dict(url=URL('my_other_page', vars=vars)))
```

Note, if you intend to insert the above in a web2py view, the HTML markup will be escaped by default, so you would have to wrap it in `XML()` to prevent the escaping:

```
{{=XML(T('Here is a string to <a href="%(url)s">translate</a>',
         dict(url=URL('my_other_page', vars=vars))))}}
```

Comment: is there a way to use the built-in helpers like `A()` to insert the URL without having to use `XML()`?

Comment: Ultimately what gets translated must be a string. If you want to use the `A()` helper, you would have to separately translate its text (i.e., `A(T('link text'), ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest way is first translate with a placeholder like:

```
Here is a string to <a href="@URL@">translate</a>
```

and second substitute the placeholder @URL@ with `URL('my_other_page', vars=vars)`

The only risk is the corruption of code or placeholder during translation.

Comment: But when I do `T('here is <a href="">a link</a>')`, the html is escaped by web2py. Is there a way using the `A()` html helper function?

Comment: @user2667066, note that the HTML is not escaped by `T()`. Rather, you are likely inserting the translated string in a web2py view, and strings written to views are escaped by default, unless wrapped in `XML()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42792054/440323.

Comment: @Paolo Betti, you can do this with standard Python string formatting (i.e., using `%(placeholder)s` syntax), as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Internationalization--and-Pluralization-with-T) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42792054/440323).

Comment: @Anthony you are right, this is text that is shown in a view. Whats the best way to provide translations, either of strings in a view, or perhaps even of an entire page? At the moment I'm taking paragraphs in the view and wrapping them in `{{=T('This used to be the text')}}`, which I guess is wrong.

Comment: That approach is fine -- just wrap in `XML()` if it contains markup that you do not want escaped (though be careful -- circumventing the default escaping is dangerous if the text includes any user-provided input).